# Adding p-value for Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test to box plots with 3 groups (repeated measures)

Tags: rank, box, signed, p-value

The dataset involves values measured at baseline and then two subsequent timepoints for the same group of participants; hence I wanted to run the Wilcox Signed Rank Test.  I can create the box plots for the data, but when I try to use the code I know for adding p-values it seems to be adding Wilcox Rank Sum Test value.

The format of the output is good - just the wrong test results.

```
`ggplot(r, aes(x=days, y=value, fill=days)) + 
  geom_boxplot( alpha=0.2) + 
  xlab("Days") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparegroups)  `
```

When I run the test separately with this code, the p-values are different.

```
`wilcox.exact(Day_1,Day_15, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
wilcox.exact(Day_1,Day_45, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
wilcox.exact(Day_15,Day_45, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")`
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit further.  Perhaps, the box plot is not appropriate for non-parametric paired data - as I'm looking at the median paired difference not the difference in medians?